# Replace ip address and port in login.java with their value from text file

Tags: java, android, web-services, url, text-files

I'm working on an android application of register of user into database with webservice (script php).

In register.java, I have:

```
 private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.30:80/webservice/register.php";
```

I want to not put IP and Port in these codes and retrieve them from a text file. So, I made a text file in it I put :IP = 192.168.1.30
Port = 80
and the configuration.java:

```
package com.example.app;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public  class Configuration
{

public void getparams() throws IOException{
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("C:/.../configuration.txt");   
        try {
              properties.load(fileStream);
              properties.get("IP");
              properties.get("Port");
             } finally {
              fileStream.close();
        }
    }

}
```

How can I call the port number and ip address in the url of register.java?

Comment: the configuration.java:
`import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public  class Configuration
{
public void getparams() throws IOException{
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("C:/.../configuration.txt");   
  try {
        properties.load(fileStream);
        properties.get("IP");
        properties.get("Port");
          
  } finally {
        fileStream.close();
  }
 }
 
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Properties class available in java to load properties from a file.

Please check this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/